# How to enable `/std:c++latest` in cmake?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I can set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` to `17` to get `/std:c++17`, but I can't set it to `latest`, can I? I guess I can just brute-force it with

```
if (MSVC)
    add_compiler_options(/std:c++latest)
endif()
```

of course, but is there an idiomatic way to get `/std:c++latest`, maybe even toolchain-agnostic?

**EDIT** Why would anybody want this? Unlike Clang and GCC, MSVC doesn't seem to define `/std:c++2a` to enable post-C++17 features. It simply uses `/std:c++latest` for that. If I'm building a code base with a set of known compilers, I know which C++20 features I can use, but I need to tell the build system to enable everything each compiler is capable of.

Comment: I'm not aware of any compiler (or toolchain) that provides such a thing.   Most vendors expect the user to know, and deliberately select, the standard they build for (and default to a standard for which their support is stable and near-complete).   Since the latest is often developmental and unstable, selecting the latest version is really for highly knowledgeable and advanced developers who are willing and able to cope with incomplete or incorrect implementations of the language or library.   And those developers will probably know exactly what version of the standard they wish to use.

Comment: The variable `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` is really the only "toolchain-agnostic" way to set the C++ version to use. And it only allows specific pre-defined values, unfortunately. Also, neither GCC nor Clang have a "latest" standard option IIRC.

Comment: While I understand your motivation for wanting this feature, it would severely undermine the portability of a given codebase and CMake build system. The definition of "latest" would shift significantly between different compilers and even compiler versions. Best to be explicit about which version you want.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude adding rationale to the question, I realized that Clang and GCC just use a different way to enable latest. For those compilers, you say `-std=c++1z` or `-std=c++2a`, and those stay around forever, eventually becoming aliases for `-std=c++17` and `-std=c++20`, resp. `/std:c++latest`, otoh, is a moving target. After C++20, it will become what GCC and Clang will likely call `-std=c++2b`. I think I like the GCC/Clang way better, for the reasons that Botje and Peter correctly pointed out in their comments.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Until CMake 3.20.3, if you ask for C++20, using `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)`, you'll get `-std:c++latest`. Proof:

```
  if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 19.12.25835)
    set(CMAKE_CXX20_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION "-std:c++latest")
    set(CMAKE_CXX20_EXTENSION_COMPILE_OPTION "-std:c++latest")
  endif()
```

(from Modules/Compiler/MSVC-CXX.cmake in the cmake sources)

UPDATE: Since CMake 3.20.4, `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)` gets you `-std:c++20`, so you need `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)` to get `-std:c++latest` -- assuming that your MSVC compiler version is 16.11 Preview 1 or later (see cmake commit 3aaf1d91bf353).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you use a compiler that is already C++20 compliant and you don't want to put an "if" and an extra assignment, as was done in a previous answer, this is a standard way to put the latest version of C++ with CMake when using Visual Studio or another compiler.

```
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_20)
```

Here is the list of features supported by CMake in the case of C++ [CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html).

Answer (score -5):

> Supported values are 98, 11, 14, 17, and 20.

According to the [CMake Docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html)